# Tick a checkbox in a table cell by clicking anywhere in the table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, but I can't find the information anywhere. Basically, I have a table with each cell containing a checkbox. I want to be able to tick the checkbox by clicking anywhere within the cell. I can't figure out how to do it, Javascript would be the best type of solution for me but I could also use jQuery.

Here is a row of my table I wish to do this in:

```
<tr>
    <td><center>9:00 - 10:00</center></td>
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon09"></center></td>
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="tue09"></center></td>
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="wed09"></center></td>
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="thu09"></center></td>
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="fri09"></center></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onload() {
                var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
                for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
                    tds[i].onclick = 
                                    function(td) { 
                                        return function() { 
                                            tdOnclick(td); 
                                        }; 
                                    }(tds[i]); 
                }
                var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    inputs[i].onclick = 
                                    function(input){ 
                                        return function() { 
                                            inputOnclick(input); 
                                        };
                                    }(inputs[i]); 
                }
            }
            function tdOnclick(td) {
                for(var i = 0; i < td.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    if(td.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
                        if(td.childNodes[i].nodeName == "INPUT") {
                            if(td.childNodes[i].checked) {
                                td.childNodes[i].checked = false;
                                td.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                            } else {
                                td.childNodes[i].checked = true;
                                td.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                            }
                        } else {
                            tdOnclick(td.childNodes[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            function inputOnclick(input) {
                input.checked = !input.checked;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload()">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><center>9:00 - 10:00</center></td>
                <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon09"></center></td>
                <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="tue09"></center></td>
                <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="wed09"></center></td>
                <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="thu09"></center></td>
                <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="fri09"></center></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me. Just one more question, do you know how to get the table cell to change colour once it is ticked?

Comment: Works great, thanks. The only problem I have now is that it just colours in the middle part of the cell. Here is a screenshot of what I get. http://i.imgur.com/bDrBU.png

Comment: I can't say how to solve that, without checking it live with firebug; I suspect the cause of this is cellspacing or borders.

Comment: Yeah I have used firebug, when I hover over the cell, the correct area is highlighted. There is some cellspacing in my CSS, don't know how I'll fix it.

Answer (score 19):

Why not use a pure CSS solution? This makes use of label tag to achieve what you desire.

```
<tr>
    <td><center>9:00 - 10:00</center></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon09"></label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="tue09"></label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="wed09"></label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="thu09"></label></td>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="fri09"></label></td>
</tr>

<style type="text/css">
    td label { 
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

For a more advanced working demonstration, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/8q5TQ/7/

Comment: +1 I was about to post a similar answer, but you beat me to the punch, so I just pasted my HTML into your answer. I hope that's okay. If not, click the edit button, and use the drop-down at the top of the edit form to roll back.

Comment: as long as it helps and answers the question I'm totally OK with it :) feel free to edit the response (u explained it much better than i did ;))

Comment: This seems like a very nice solution, but again, it doesn't work on my table for some reason.

Comment: @OisínDorgan just a wild guess there must be some other CSS property which is messing things up so you might wanna take a look at all the CSS property the table, tr, td and label is inheriting

Comment: Thank you again. Is there any way to change the colour of the cell once it is selected using CSS?

Comment: @OisínDorgan there is a way to do that but u'll have to use CSS3 selectors and won't work on older/IE browsers hence I wouldn't recommend that but just to demonstrate how to achieve it using CSS3 here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/qqc8U/1/

Comment: Whilst elegant, this doesn't work if your table cell has padding. Easy right, just specify a -ve padding on the label? Not so easy if you're using a framework that calculates padding from classes.

Comment: @AndyBrown well, there is a way to circumvent that but for me it's a bit ugly

http://jsfiddle.net/19xefu6g/

The label is now absolutely positioned and is stretched throughout the td and td has position relative for obvious reasons. Now, it wouldn't matter if td has padding.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcDMW/2/)

```
$(function(){
    $('table tr td').on('click', function(e){
        if(e.target.type=="checkbox")
        {        
            if($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).attr('checked', false);
            else $(this).attr('checked', true);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) 
                $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
            else
                $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working after applying the 'for' attribute to the label element:

```
<tr>
    <td><center>9:00 - 10:00</center></td>
    <td><label for="mon09"><center><input type="checkbox" name="free" value="mon09" id="mon09"></center></label></td>
    <!-- etc. -->
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8zq3/) a demo for you

Basically what you need is

```
$(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
        $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Function for checks in table :**

```
    function Checkpoint() {
      var chks = document.getElementById("idmytable").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<chks.length; i++) 
        {
            if (chks[i].type == "checkbox" &  chks[i].checked==true)
               {
                    alert(chks[i].id);
               }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, `code` only answers are highly discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I couldn't use the elegant CSS `label` technique because padding in the `td` element prevented the `label` from filling the whole cell and the framework in use made it impractical to calculate a negative label padding.

This jquery snippet attaches a `click` event to the `td` that will toggle the checkbox as long as the original event target was not the checkbox itself (omit this check and it will appear that directly hitting the checkbox does nothing because it will be double-processed). Additionally, the `change` event will be invoked to ensure that your UI handlers are called.

```js
$("td").on("click", function (event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is("input[type='checkbox']")) {
    cb = $("input:checkbox", this)
    cb.prop("checked", !cb.prop("checked"))
    cb.change()
  }
})
```

Change the `td` selector to suit your page structure.

Answer (score -1):

You'd want something like this. Not quite awake yet, so probably won't work, but basically:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() { // find all checkboxes
   $(this).parent('td').click(function() { // find the td containing the checkbox
      // attach a click even to the td which toggles the checkbox within
      cb = $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]'); 
      cb.checked = !cb.checked;
   });
});
```